# when we scroll tableview then images in table changes and override, how to manage this?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *cellIdentifier= @"Identifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    UIImageView *typeImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 15, 15)];
    [cell addSubview:typeImageView];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {

    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
         typeImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Here section 0 contain no imageview but when we scroll then image added in section 0. Everytime, when we scroll tableview images overridden to previous one.

Answer (score 0):

This is a cell dequeue problem. Try to set nil in the section 0 image view.
Also you are adding a image view as subview for all cells. This will get the problem. When adding subview check whether subview already exists or not. 
I hope this is useful.

Comment: thanks for your reply. How to check an imageview exist in cell.